# Streaming push-notification on muted phone

Tags: android, ios, push-notification

I'm looking for a feature I'm finding surprisingly difficult to research.

I want to emulate a feature I know from another app in my own.

Here's what the app does:

- it is a baby monitor, one device is in a room, and on noise (in the use case of the app: a crying baby), a push notification to other, connected devices is triggered
- the other devices are connected via the internet
- when the notification is triggered, the receiving phones play the streamed sound from the room, not just briefly, but continuously
- this works even if the phones are locked
- it works both on iOS and Android

I would like to send such a push to a self-written app. Sender would be some server, receiver would be Android and iOS devices.

How is this type of push notification called in iOS and Android terms, respectively? Where can I find documentation for it?

Comment: Cloud messaging you mean? https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging

Comment: This sounds wrong. The page you linked says it's restricted to 4 kB of payload. The app I mentioned plays a sound, possibly a minute long, which certainly is bigger than 4 kB.

Comment: You need ios push notifications which will run your app on receiving it so you'll be able to start playing some sound. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1

Comment: @Demosthenes The notification is small and tells it to start streaming.  It would stream from a URL on the server.  The push itself may not have any data, or maybe only a single message_type field.

Comment: @GabeSechan I think we're getting closer: The notification tells the app to wake, and the app then runs in the background and streams? Is that how it works?

Comment: YEah.  In response to getting the message, the receiver will start a foreground service (a foreground service doesn't mean it has a UI, it means its a high priority service with a notification for the user to know its running) that does the actual streaming.

Comment: The receiver being the app, I presume? And sound playback then works like what e.g. Spotify does, play while app in Background?